# Count permutations with given cost and divisbilty

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, permutations

I am given $N$ . We need to count such permutations of $N$ numbers with each element between $0$ to $9$ which satisfy following conditions :

1. **Cost of permutation** is less than or equal to given $M$. Here cost of permutation means sum of all the elements . Like if permutation is {$1,2,3$} then cost of this permutation is $1+2+3=6$.
2. If the permutation is represented ad decimal number then it must be **divisible by given P**. Like if permutation is {$1,2$} then $12$ is the number and its divisible by $2,3,4$ etc.

We need to count such permutations of size $N$.

**Example** : Let $N=2$ , $M=3$ and $P=3$ then here answer is $5$. As we can have $5$ permutations whose decimal representation is divisible by $3$. They are :

1. **{$0,0$}** : Its decimal representation is $00$ and its divisible by $3$ and also cost of permutation is $0+0 = 0 <= M$
2. **{$0,3$}** : Its decimal representation is $03$ and its divisible by $3$ and also cost of permutation is $0+3 = 3 <= M$
3. **{$2,1$}** : Its decimal representation is $21$ and its divisible by $3$ and also cost of permutation is $2+1 = 3 <= M$
4. **{$3,0$}** : Its decimal representation is $30$ and its divisible by $3$ and also cost of permutation is $3+0 = 3 <= M$
5. **{$1,2$}** : Its decimal representation is $12$ and its divisible by $3$ and also cost of permutation is $1+2 = 3 <= M$

Can their be some formula if we are given these $N,M$ and $P$ ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is the sum of coefficients of $x^0,\ldots,x^M$ in the generating function
$$
\frac{1}{P} \sum_{r=0}^{P-1} \prod_{k=0}^{N-1} \sum_{j=0}^9 (\omega^{10^kr}x)^j, \quad \omega = e^{2\pi i/P}.
$$
For example, taking $N=2$ and $P=3$, the resulting generating function is
$$ x^{18} + 4x^{15} + 7x^{12} + 10x^9 + 7x^6 + 4x^3 + 1, $$
and so the answer for $M=3$ is $1 + 4 = 5$.

Another approach is, given $M$ and $P$, to construct a DFA that accepts your language. You can then compute a rational function $R(x)$ such that the coefficient of $x^N$ is the answer for a given $N$. In principle you can convert this to an explicit formula even without constructing the DFA.

Comment: Can you explain your DFA approach ?

Comment: Constructing the DFA itself is standard so I'll skip it. Given the DFA, Wikipedia has a few links explaining how to get the generating function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#The_number_of_words_in_a_regular_language.

Comment: Ok Can their be some more precise formula that can be computed for large N ?

Comment: The rational function implies a precise (exact!) formula, which depends on $M$ and $P$. You always get an exact formula from a rational generating function.

Comment: Can you please explain. I am not able to get it in context of this question ? What  rational generating function are you talking about ?

Comment: The generating function for the number of words of length $N$ accepted by the DFA. It can be calculated from the DFA by diagonalizing (or more generally, computing the Jordan form of) a matrix, and perhaps by other methods. This is hopefully explained in links 20–23 of the Wikipedia article (which actually give the exact formula rather than just the generating function). You'll have to construct the DFA yourself.

Comment: Will their be a single dfa for all N,M , P ?Please help to construct the DFA.

Comment: No, for each $M,P$ there will be a different DFA that works for all $N$. Make sure you know what a DFA is. I won't help you construct one, though.

Comment: Ok..Thanx for help

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Whoa! Did not see *that* coming. Well done, +1

Comment: @HammyTheGreek ANy help in constructing the DFA ?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Hey what you mean by this 
  "In principle you can convert this to an explicit formula even without constructing the DFA." ?

Comment: @user3786422: Sorry, not my area of expertise. That said, how large do you expect your $n$ to be? Even on a lowly netbook and non-compiled code, using the answer on $n,m,p$ of 100, 500, 6 took only seconds.

Comment: @HammyTheGreek N can be upto 10^9 , 1 ≤ P ≤ 16 and  1 ≤ M ≤ 15000. Assume I have 15 seconds to calculate the answer. I know answer can be very large so i want total answer modulo 10^9 + 7

Comment: @user3786422: I may do some quick timings on one of my workstations if I have time, will reply if/when I do. In any case, it would be useful to add context to your query: what are you getting at with the calculation? Context of what you're trying to do might get an "ah-ha!" from an unexpected place...

Comment: @HammyTheGreek It's a programming competition. Here the idea is to use some sort of dynamic programming. But I think it beats the purpose for us to help the OP cheat in their competition.

Comment: @user3786422 By "In principle you can convert this to an explicit formula even without constructing the DFA" I meant that there could be some trick which will allow you to calculate this explicit formula directly, though it might be tricky to find. In any case, that's not how you're supposed to do this exercise. You're supposed to use (probably) dynamic programming of some sort. I'll let you figure out how.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yeah Dynammic programming will work out. Am also thinking in same direction.If you get some clue do add to your solution..:)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Agreed. user3786422 - think about the rules for checking divisibility... the rest should fall into place for you pretty quickly...

Comment: @HammyTheGreek Can you please explain how rules for checking divisibility will work out (say we assume that P is less say upto 5) . Then what ? How we can work on N which can be very large.